# Why does the "columnToggle"-Button animation does not change?

Tags: datatables

in my table I show/hide columns based on their class attribute. Everything works fine except that that the animation of the "columnToggle"-Button does not change. Therefor it is hard to see which groups have been selected.

Here is a test case on Datatables live with the same behavior : [DataTables Live Example](http://live.datatables.net/maxituva/1/edit)

What am I missing? Thanks for your help.

sanJo

Comment: There is no way to use animation for this, and without setting table-layout:fixed I think it would be exceptionally difficult to do.

Comment: Why do you think it would be difficult? I dont want to sound annoyed, but it is a "toggle"-button and it works in [this](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/column_visibility/columnsToggle.html) example of datatables documentation. Instead my buttons always looks "pressed".

Comment: I'm having a hard time following your code, but at the most basic level (as you probably noticed), both buttons start with a class of `active`. I'm not totally sure how you're setting this though. One needs to be set as `active` at start and then you can set your toggle appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug in the current version of Datatables. The "active" argument is not set properly. My workaround was to toggle the "active" argument with jquery toggleClass function.